# What am I doing wrong in this method? (Using StringBuilder to create a new word from 4 strings)

Tags: java

I'm supposed to grab 4 strings from a scanner in my main method (s1, s2, s3, and s4-- the main method works perfectly after testing) and call this:

--> concat(s1, s2, s3, s4);

The method name, `concat`, is probably misleading, because I don't just want `s1+s2+s3+s4`. What I really need is to start with `s1`, and then add characters from `s2`, `s3` and `s4` that aren't already present in the result `String`. For example, if `s1` is "drain" and `s2` is "dane", the partial result after processing `s2` would be "draine" since the `d`, `a` and `n` are already present in the result `String`.

Here is the method:

```
public static void concat(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4) {

      String str;
      StringBuilder createdWord = new StringBuilder();      

      for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
         char c = s1.charAt(i);
         for (int j = 0; j < createdWord.length(); j++) {
            if (createdWord.charAt(j) != c)
               createdWord.append(c);             
         }                  
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
         char c = s2.charAt(i);
         for (int j = 0; j < createdWord.length(); j++) {
            if (createdWord.charAt(j) != c)
               createdWord.append(c);             
         }         
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < s3.length(); i++) {
         char c = s3.charAt(i);
         for (int j = 0; j < createdWord.length(); j++) {
            if (createdWord.charAt(j) != c)
               createdWord.append(c);             
         }         
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < s4.length(); i++) {
         char c = s4.charAt(i);
         for (int j = 0; j < createdWord.length(); j++) {
            if (createdWord.charAt(j) != c)
               createdWord.append(c);             
         }         
      }

      str = createdWord.toString();
      System.out.println(str);

   }
```

When I try to print (str), I get a blank output. I am positive that there's a way to make this simpler.

I'll accept the answer based on clarity, simplicity, and/or an easier solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just edited to bring into the question your point from comments on one of the answers. Did I get it, or is there still some subtlety that needs to be expressed?

Comment: Yeah, that makes a lot of sense. I see where the confusion was. Thanks, Erick, that was a very poor choice of names to call my method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the lines where you have a for loop :

```
for (int j = 0; j < createdWord.length(); j++)
```

Since createdWord is just initialized, it's length is zero (0) thus createdWord.length() = 0 and the code inside the for loops is never reached.
You should try to fix this.

**EDIT**
Well here is how simply I would refactor the concat method. I am also providing a main and 4 string to tests. According to the OP comments, the expected system out would be "drainemv"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "drain";
    String str2 = "dane";
    String str3 = "main";
    String str4 = "vain";

    concat(str1, str2, str3, str4);

}
public static void concat(String s1, String s2, String s3, String s4) {

    String str;
    StringBuilder createdWord = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i++) {
        char c = s1.charAt(i);
        if(createdWord.length() ==0) {
            createdWord.append(c);
        } else if (!createdWord.toString().contains(String.valueOf(c))){
            createdWord.append(c);
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s2.length(); i++) {
        char c = s2.charAt(i);
        if(createdWord.length() ==0) {
            createdWord.append(c);
        } else if (!createdWord.toString().contains(String.valueOf(c))){
            createdWord.append(c);
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s3.length(); i++) {
        char c = s3.charAt(i);
        if(createdWord.length() ==0) {
            createdWord.append(c);
        } else if (!createdWord.toString().contains(String.valueOf(c))){
            createdWord.append(c);
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s4.length(); i++) {
        char c = s4.charAt(i);
        if(createdWord.length() ==0) {
            createdWord.append(c);
        } else if (!createdWord.toString().contains(String.valueOf(c))){
            createdWord.append(c);
        }

    }


    str = createdWord.toString();
    System.out.println(str);

}
```

Comment: Good call. You are absolutely correct. Do you have a suggestion as to how OP might fix it?

Comment: Thank you, great catch! After multiple edits to my code, I was trying to do this BEFORE using StringBuilder and this slipped in there... I changed it to the same length as s1, s2, s3, and s4 now in the nested for loop and now I'm getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0" after the user types in the 4th word... even though it compiles fine.

Comment: On which line is the `Exception` thrown? (Keeping in mind that we can't tell what numbers are assigned to the lines you've given us.)

Comment: Thank you so much! All of you! This answer was the solution that fixed it. That "if" statement fixed my problems AND got rid of an unnecessary "for loop." Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help, I am sure the code I posted can be optimized a lot more. I just wanted it to be as much closer to the original code to help the OP understand the solution

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue has been identified, but here is more brief approach:

```
    String s1 = "bla";
    String s2 = "yata";
    String s3 = "test";
    String s4 = "moretest";

    String[] sr = new String[]{s1, s2, s3, s4};

    StringBuilder sbNewWord = new StringBuilder();

    sbNewWord.append(sr[0]);

    for(int ndx=1; ndx<sr.length; ndx++) {
        for(char c : sr[ndx].toCharArray()) {
            if(sbNewWord.toString().indexOf(c) == -1) {
                sbNewWord.append(c);
            }
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT:

newword:  blaytesmor

Answer (score 0):

Using some Java 8 features here is how you can do it.
LinkedHashSet preserves the order of insertion.

```
import java.util.*;

class Test003 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        String s1 = "test";
        String s2 = "test24m";
        String s3 = "test1";
        String s4 = "test3";

        LinkedHashSet<Character> hs = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
        hs.addAll(Arrays.asList(s1.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).toArray(Character[]::new)));
        hs.addAll(Arrays.asList(s2.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).toArray(Character[]::new)));
        hs.addAll(Arrays.asList(s3.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).toArray(Character[]::new)));
        hs.addAll(Arrays.asList(s4.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).toArray(Character[]::new)));

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        hs.forEach(b::append);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

And here is how you can do it without Java 8 features.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;

public class Test004 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        String s1 = "test";
        String s2 = "test24m";
        String s3 = "test1";
        String s4 = "test3";

        LinkedHashSet<Character> hs = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
        hs.addAll(Arrays.asList(toCharacterArray(s1.toCharArray())));
        hs.addAll(Arrays.asList(toCharacterArray(s2.toCharArray())));
        hs.addAll(Arrays.asList(toCharacterArray(s3.toCharArray())));
        hs.addAll(Arrays.asList(toCharacterArray(s4.toCharArray())));

        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<Character> it = hs.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()){
            b.append(it.next());
        }
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    private static Character[] toCharacterArray(char[] c){
        Character[] result = new Character[c.length];
        for (int i=0; i<c.length; i++){
            result[i] = c[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```